# Converter design between data objects in python

Tags: python, design-patterns, converters

I'm implementing a library for similar data objects that can be converted to each other. To make it more illustrative, I'll assume in the following that the data objects are different image types. Say, I have the following classes

```
class PixelImage(object):
    pass

class VectorImage(object):
    pass

class FourierImage(object):
    pass
```

What is a good way to set up converter functions between those? Are there any design patterns for such a case? The problem is that a converter needs a certain amount of knowledge both, on the source class and on the target class, but I'd like to prevent a strong dependency between the classes. Moreover, it would be good if design is open to add derived classes later on (e.g. `class CompressedPixelImage(PixelImage)`).

Below I'll discuss two solutions I've come up with. Alternative approaches and comments are highly welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a factory?

Answer (score 0):

*Solution 1*: Use Member functions `to_TargetFormat()`, e.g.

```
pixel_image = PixelImage()
vector_image = pixel_image.to_vector()
```

Advantage: It's short and users can see the possible conversions of an object directly in the API (for example in an interactive ipython shell).

Disadvantage: We get tight coupling. PixelImage has to know about the VectorImage class, in particular it's constructor, because it has to create the VectorImage object. If I have a lot of classes, each hat to import all others.

*Solution 2*: Use class methods `from_SourceFormat()`, e.g.

```
pixel_image = PixelImage()
vector_image = VectorImage.from_pixel(pixel_image)
```

Advantage: No explicit coupling. We can feed in any pixel_image-like object and benefit from duck-typing.
Disadvantage: The class method call looks less elegant and maybe it's less intuitive for a user.

Comment: Solution 3: Use a 3rd generic `Image` object which contains conversion logic. This also effectively prevents coupling as knowledge about the other formats is not required for any class besides the generic one.

Comment: How would you define the API then?

Comment: Another approach: create an abstract `Image` base class from which the others inherit. Then create a converter/factory method in its own utility class that knows how to convert between the different `Image` types (using public methods/attributes only) and returns a new object of the requested type based on the one passed into it. It could have a signature like `def convert_image(image: Image, name: str) -> Image`. Example call: `vector_image = ImageConverter.convert_image(pixel_image, 'VectorImage')`.

Comment: Follow-up: if you're happy to import the target class in the code where you call the converter, then you could make the second argument a class (e.g., `to_type: typing.Type[Image]` instead of `str`. Then the same example call would become `vector_image = ImageConverter.convert_image(pixel_image, VectorImage)`.